# First and last row in MySQL database table for date and customer

Tags: mysql

With this **SQL** query on **MySQL database table** I have selected the **first access** on my application web for current date and for customer :

```
mysql> SELECT
    (@cnt := @cnt + 1) AS rowNumber,
    t.myDate,
    t.myCustomer
FROM
    tbl_new AS t
CROSS JOIN (SELECT @cnt := 0) AS dummy
WHERE
    t.myDate IN (CURDATE())
ORDER BY
    t.myDate DESC
LIMIT 1;
+-----------+------------+------------+
| rowNumber | myDate     | myCustomer |
+-----------+------------+------------+
|         1 | 2018-11-12 | 561731A    |
+-----------+------------+------------+
1 row in set
```

With this **SQL** query on **MySQL database** table I have selected the **last access** on my webpage for current date and for customer :

```
mysql> SELECT
    (@cnt := @cnt + 1) AS rowNumber,
    myDate,
    myCustomer
FROM
    tbl_new
ORDER BY
    myDate DESC
LIMIT 1;
+-----------+------------+------------+
| rowNumber | myDate     | myCustomer |
+-----------+------------+------------+
|         2 | 2018-11-12 | 719020A    |
+-----------+------------+------------+
1 row in set
```

Now I need **UNION ALL** these SQL queries for unique output, but the output of last access is wrong 908324A instead of 719020A,

Why ?

```
mysql> SELECT
    (@cnt := @cnt + 1) AS rowNumber,
    t.myDate,
    t.myCustomer
FROM
    tbl_new AS t
CROSS JOIN (SELECT @cnt := 0) AS dummy
WHERE
    t.myDate IN (CURDATE())
UNION ALL
    SELECT
    (@cnt := @cnt + 1) AS rowNumber,
    myDate,
    myCustomer
FROM
    tbl_new
ORDER BY
    myDate DESC
    LIMIT 2;
+-----------+------------+------------+
| rowNumber | myData     | myCustomer |
+-----------+------------+------------+
|    246616 | 2018-11-12 | 561731A    |
|    111872 | 2018-11-12 | 908324A    |
+-----------+------------+------------+
2 rows in set
```

Comment: Please provide some sample data (preferably a DB/SQL Fiddle). You possible need parentheses around `select` statements in `union`.

Comment: Move order by and limit to each individual query.

Answer (score 1):

I'd say your sql should be like this:

```
SELECT
    (@cnt := @cnt + 1) AS rowNumber,
    t.myDate,
    t.myCustomer
FROM
    tbl_new AS t
CROSS JOIN (SELECT @cnt := 0) AS dummy
WHERE
    t.myDate IN (CURDATE())
ORDER BY
    t.myDate DESC
LIMIT 1
UNION ALL
SELECT
    (@cnt := @cnt + 1) AS rowNumber,
    myDate,
    myCustomer
FROM
    tbl_new
ORDER BY
    myDate DESC
LIMIT 1
```

Just your two sentences with UNON ALL.

**EDITED**

I cannot post comments.
May be you can try putting the queries in parenthesis:

```
SELECT * FROM (
SELECT (@cnt := @cnt + 1) AS rowNumber,
...
ORDER BY ...
)
UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM ( ... )
```

Not sure, if you can provide a fiddle...

Comment: Thank you but the output not change and ORDER BY clause first UNION ALL syntax generate error [Err] 1221 - Incorrect usage of UNION and ORDER BY